# duplicate values between databases

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql, database

I have 15 different MySQL databases from different clients that are all the same structure and I am looking for a way to see witch customers exist in more then one of my clients databases.They would have the same SSN in each database to search for. Any thing that could help point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you could write an application which connects to the databases, queries them, and compares the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the databases are all in the same MySQL instance, and you have a user that has privileges on all 15 databases...

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT a.ssn 
     , GROUP_CONCAT(a.src ORDER BY a.src)
  FROM (
         SELECT 'db01' AS src, t01.ssn FROM database_one.mytable t01
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'db02' AS src, t02.ssn FROM database_two.mytable t02
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'db03' AS src, t03.ssn FROM database_three.mytable t03
            ...
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'db15' AS src, t15.ssn FROM database_fifteen.mytable t15
       ) a
   GROUP BY a.ssn
  HAVING SUM(1) > 1
```

Note that this will require MySQL to materialize a resultset of ALL ssn from all rows from the table in all fifteen databases, which could be a sizable set, so you would need to have sufficient temp space, and the time to perform the sort operation to identify the "duplicates". For a large set, this could crank a while, so also be aware of lock contention (impacting other activity on those tables.)

---

**EDIT**

Fifteen separate MySQL instances will require fifteen separate MySQL database connections.

What I would do: extract the list of ssn from each database, each into a separate flat file. Then load all fifteen flat files into a single table (on a separate database). The MySQL `LOAD DATA` statement is convenient way to do this.

The end result of that I would have a table that looks like the inline view, aliased as `a`, in the query above. To identify "duplicates", the outer query would be the same...

```
SELECT a.ssn
     , GROUP_CONCAT(a.src ORDER BY a.src)
  FROM all_ssns s
 GROUP BY a.ssn
HAVING SUM(1) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help. In my case since the program that accesses the database does not allow to select a database name all the databases are on separate mysql instances :(